# nginx configuration for node subdomain gives 502 error

Tags: docker, nginx

I am using the docker image linuxserver/letsencrypt.

I am trying to run a static website with a node subdomain.

my nginx configuration is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    root /config/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name dreamingoftech.uk www.dreamingoftech.uk;

    # all ssl related config moved to ssl.conf
    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

#   client_max_body_size 0;

#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$args =404;
#   }

}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
#
#   root /config/www;
#   index index.html index.htm index.php;
#
    server_name api.dreamingoftech.uk;
#
    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;
#
#   include /config/nginx/ldap.conf;
#
#   client_max_body_size 0;
#
    location / {
#       include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
#       resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
#                proxy_set_header Host api.dreamingoftech.uk;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

I would appreciate some assistance in figuring out the problem.
I have dockerised my app and have them running on the same virtual netwoork.

I can also curl the api homepage from the server so I know it is up.

The static site works ok, but i get a 502 error on the subdomain.

Comment: Does it have - error log?

Comment: I honestly don't know where to look for an error log. Would it be inside the docker container?

Comment: you can run `docker logs <containerid>`

Comment: Sorry for the delay I have been on holiday. The only thing in the logs is to do with an error that the forums say is unimportant in most cases

Comment: After more digging I have found this error: 
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out.

I had to add a network bridge within my docker-compose file.

Then in the Nginx upstream configuration I had to reference the node applications docker name not localhost

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check first if http://localhost:4000 does show a web page when loaded. If not, it will cause error. Also there is no index page or root configured which can be used in case nginx is not able to find it

Comment: Hi. Yes I have checked that http://localhost :4000 returns a page. And it does. This was the curl that I mentioned.

Comment: Have you seen https://albertogrespan.com/blog/running-multiple-domains-or-subdomains-in-nginx-with-server-blocks/ ? You can try using different config file for just your sub-domain if it is causing conflicts.

Comment: Hi. I did originally have the config separate. However for simplicity in troubleshooting I merged them together